# How do I mock a REST template exchange?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have a service in which I need to ask an outside server via rest for some information:

```
public class SomeService {

    public List<ObjectA> getListofObjectsA() {
        List<ObjectA> objectAList = new ArrayList<ObjectA>();
        ParameterizedTypeReference<List<ObjectA>> typeRef = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<ObjectA>>() {};
        ResponseEntity<List<ObjectA>> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange("/objects/get-objectA", HttpMethod.POST, new HttpEntity<>(ObjectAList), typeRef);
        return responseEntity.getBody();
    }
}
```

How can I write a JUnit test for `getListofObjectsA()`?

I have tried with the below:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SomeServiceTest {
    private MockRestServiceServer mockServer;

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Inject
   private SomeService underTest;

@Before
public void setup() {
    mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
    underTest = new SomeService(restTemplate);
    mockServer.expect(requestTo("/objects/get-objectA")).andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
            .andRespond(withSuccess("{json list response}", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
}

    @Test
    public void testGetObjectAList() {
    List<ObjectA> res = underTest.getListofObjectsA();
    Assert.assertEquals(myobjectA, res.get(0));
}
```

However the above code does not work, it shows that `responseEntitty` is `null`.  How can I correct my test to properly mock `restTemplate.exchange`?

Comment: anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You don't need `MockRestServiceServer` object. The annotation is `@InjectMocks` not `@Inject`. Below is an example code that should work

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SomeServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @InjectMocks
    private SomeService underTest;

    @Test
    public void testGetObjectAList() {
        ObjectA myobjectA = new ObjectA();
        //define the entity you want the exchange to return
        ResponseEntity<List<ObjectA>> myEntity = new ResponseEntity<List<ObjectA>>(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
        Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(
            Matchers.eq("/objects/get-objectA"),
            Matchers.eq(HttpMethod.POST),
            Matchers.<HttpEntity<List<ObjectA>>>any(),
            Matchers.<ParameterizedTypeReference<List<ObjectA>>>any())
        ).thenReturn(myEntity);

        List<ObjectA> res = underTest.getListofObjectsA();
        Assert.assertEquals(myobjectA, res.get(0));
    }
```

Comment: How do we add contents to the myEntity.getBody()? Mine comes back null

Comment: Matchers are deprecated, you should use Mockito

Comment: @Angelina since it's a real object just use an appropriate constructor i.e `ResponseEntity(T body, HttpStatus status)`

Comment: @Mindaugas I´ve used the constructor but my response still is null  ResponseEntity<String> response = new ResponseEntity<>(
                "a string",HttpStatus.OK );

Comment: @Marino make sure that your mocked method that is supposed to return the response entity is being called and that it is infact configured to return said entity

Comment: I´m sorry, @Mindaugas but still doesn´t works! My test code is ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>("sampleBodyString", HttpStatus.CREATED);

        doReturn(responseEntity).when(restTemplate).exchange(anyString(), any(HttpMethod.class), any(HttpEntity.class),
                eq(String.class));

        TokenBean tokenBeanResult = tokenService.refresh("refresh-token"); and my real code is: 

        ResponseEntity<String> response
                = restTemplate.exchange(tokenApiConfig.getUrl(), HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class); and response is still null

Comment: @Marino is request parameter of type HttpEntity.class? cause that is what you are using to mock the rest template call

Comment: The Matchers class is deprecated now

Comment: `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` were a key in my test case.

Answer (score 76):

This is an example with the non deprecated [ArgumentMatchers](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.7/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html) class

```
when(restTemplate.exchange(
                ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),
                ArgumentMatchers.any(HttpMethod.class),
                ArgumentMatchers.any(),
                ArgumentMatchers.<Class<String>>any()))
             .thenReturn(responseEntity);
```

Comment: You can use it with generic matcher too. ArgumentMatchers.<Class<?>>any())

Answer (score 33):

```
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<String>("sampleBodyString", HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
when(restTemplate.exchange(
                           Matchers.anyString(), 
                           Matchers.any(HttpMethod.class),
                           Matchers.<HttpEntity<?>> any(), 
                           Matchers.<Class<String>> any()
                          )
                         ).thenReturn(responseEntity);
```

Comment: Doesn't work with `org.hamcrest.Matchers` and `org.mockito.Matchers` is deprecated in favor of hamcrest.

Comment: "Matchers" is deprecated and should be replaced with "ArgumentMatchers" because of a name clash. [Class Matchers](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.21.0/org/mockito/Matchers.html)

Answer (score 10):

For me, I had to use Matchers.any(URI.class)

```
Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(Matchers.any(URI.class), Matchers.any(HttpMethod.class), Matchers.<HttpEntity<?>> any(), Matchers.<Class<Object>> any())).thenReturn(myEntity);
```

Comment: in my case:

`when(restTemplate.exchange(any(String.class), eq(HttpMethod.GET), any(), eq(new ParameterizedTypeReference<String>() {}))).thenReturn(myEntity);`

Answer (score 7):

This work on my side.

```
ResourceBean resourceBean = initResourceBean();
ResponseEntity<ResourceBean> responseEntity  
    = new ResponseEntity<ResourceBean>(resourceBean, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
when(restTemplate.exchange(
    Matchers.anyObject(), 
    Matchers.any(HttpMethod.class),
    Matchers.<HttpEntity> any(), 
    Matchers.<Class<ResourceBean>> any())
 ).thenReturn(responseEntity);
```

Answer (score 4):

The `RestTemplate` instance has to be a real object. It should work if you create a real instance of `RestTemplate` and make it `@Spy`.

```
@Spy
private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
```

Answer (score 3):

If anyone has this problem while trying to mock restTemplate.exchange(...), the problem seems to be with matchers. As an example: the following won't work,

```
when(ecocashRestTemplate.exchange(Mockito.any()
                , Mockito.eq(HttpMethod.GET)
                , Mockito.any(HttpEntity.class)
                , Mockito.<Class<UserTransaction>>any())
        ).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(transaction, HttpStatus.OK));
```

but this one will actually work:

```
  ResponseEntity<UserTransaction> variable = new ResponseEntity<>(transaction, HttpStatus.OK);
  when(ecocashRestTemplate.exchange(Mockito.anyString()
                , Mockito.eq(HttpMethod.GET)
                , Mockito.any(HttpEntity.class)
                , Mockito.<Class<UserTransaction>>any())
   ).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(transaction, HttpStatus.OK));
```

**NOTICE** the Mockito.anyString() on the second block vs theMockito.any().

Comment: Thanks for this, I spent hours n hours but did not get any solution but yours really worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I used to get such an error. I found a more reliable solution. I have mentioned the import statements too which have worked for me. The below piece of code perfectly mocks restemplate.

import org.mockito.Matchers;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new Headers();
    headers.setExpires(10000L);     
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>("dummyString", headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    when(restTemplate.exchange( Matchers.anyString(), 
            Matchers.any(HttpMethod.class),
            Matchers.<HttpEntity<?>> any(), 
            Matchers.<Class<String>> any())).thenReturn(responseEntity);
```

Answer (score 2):

When we are testing a Client which is communicating to some external system using restTemplate, as part of unit tests we need to verify the httpEntity, headers and parameters which we are sending.

ArgumentCaptor comes handy in these situation. So here is my example (working code)

```
@Mock
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@InjectMocks
private MyClient client;

@Captor
ArgumentCaptor<HttpEntity<?>> httpEntityCaptor;

when(restTemplate.exchange(eq(expectedUrl), eq(HttpMethod.POST), Matchers.any(HttpEntity.class), eq(MyTargetResponse.class)).thenReturn(expectedResponse);

verify(restTemplate).exchange(eq(expectedUrl),eq(HttpMethod.POST), httpEntityCaptor.captor(),eq(MyTargetResponse.class));

HttpEntity<?> actualResponse = httpEntityCaptor.getValue();
HttpHeaders headers = actualResponse.getHeaders();

assertEquals(headers.getFirst("Content-Type"), "application/json");
```

Now assertions can be made based on your use case, as you have got the captured object which was sent.

Answer (score 1):

Let say you have an exchange call like below:

```
String url = "/zzz/{accountNumber}";

Optional<AccountResponse> accResponse = Optional.ofNullable(accountNumber)
        .map(account -> {


            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            headers.set("Authorization", "bearer 121212");


            HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
            ResponseEntity<AccountResponse> response = template.exchange(
                    url,
                    GET,
                    entity,
                    AccountResponse.class,
                    accountNumber
            );

            return response.getBody();
        });
```

To mock this in your test case you can use mocitko as below:

```
when(restTemplate.exchange(
        ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),
        ArgumentMatchers.any(HttpMethod.class),
        ArgumentMatchers.any(),
        ArgumentMatchers.<Class<AccountResponse>>any(),
        ArgumentMatchers.<ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Object>>>any())
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below non deprecated **ArgumentMatchers**

```
lenient().when(restTemplate.exchange(ArgumentMatchers.any(String.class), 
ArgumentMatchers.eq(HttpMethod.GET),
ArgumentMatchers.any(), 
ArgumentMatchers.eq(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<ObjectA>>() {
})))
.thenReturn(responseEntity);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

i will show a different way how to mock a restTemplate.

This way you can have several callings to obain different results.
I recommend to use Lening and use doReturn, **some IDE's recommend you to use in this way**.

If you does not want more than one call, exclude the second variable.

```
@Test
void test_ExpectedNoException() {

ResponseEntity<YourClass> first = new ResponseEntity<>(YourObject, HttpStatus.OK);

ResponseEntity<IfYouHaveAnotherClass> second = new ResponseEntity<>(IfYouHaveAnotherClassObject, HttpStatus.OK);

lenient().doReturn(first, second).when(restTemplate).exchange(Mockito.anyString()
    , Mockito.eq(HttpMethod.POST)
    , Mockito.any(HttpEntity.class)
    , Mockito.<Class<?>>any());

assertDoesNotThrow(() ->
                serviceTest.callYourMethod()
            );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented [a small library](https://github.com/antechrestos/rest-client-test) that is quite useful. It provides a `ClientHttpRequestFactory` that can receive some context. By doing so, it allows to go through all client layers such as checking that query parameters are valued, headers set, and check that deserialization works well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `RestTemplateBuilder` may be the usual thing wouldn't work. You need to add this in your test class along with when(condition).

```
@Before    
public void setup() {        
     ReflectionTestUtils.setField(service, "restTemplate", restTemplate);    
}
```

Comment: I'm using a regular rest template and this was the only thing that worked

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still facing this issue, Captor annotation worked for me

```
@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<Object> argumentCaptor;
```

Then I was able to mock the request by:

```
ResponseEntity<YourTestResponse> testEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(
    getTestFactoryResponse(), 
    HttpStatus.OK);
when(mockRestTemplate.exchange((String) argumentCaptor.capture(), 
    (HttpMethod) argumentCaptor.capture(), 
    (HttpEntity<?>) argumentCaptor.capture(), 
    (Class<YourTestResponse.class>) any())
).thenReturn(testEntity);
```

Answer (score 0):

For this specific exchange() case,
I found that easier just stub it instead, good old override:

```
var restTemplate = new RestTemplate() {
  public <T> ResponseEntity<T> exchange(URI url, HttpMethod method, @Nullable HttpEntity<?> requestEntity,
                                              Class<T> responseType) throws RestClientException {
            throw new HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    };
```

less mock stuff.. especially that api is always changing. eq(..) any().. etc.

you can check on arg inside of your stubbed exchange() before returning something or throwing exception.

--
I know that it is not the answer to that strict question. But same result. less code & easier to support.

Answer (score 0):

With mockito-core-2.23.4

```
ResponseEntity<YOUR_CLASS> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity(YOUR_CLASS_OBJECT, HttpStatus.OK);

        when(restTemplate.exchange(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.<ParameterizedTypeReference<YOUR_CLASS>> any()))
                .thenReturn(responseEntity);
```

Answer (score 0):

Was get it working this way - Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange((URI) any(), (HttpMethod) any(), (HttpEntity<?>) any(), (Class) any()))
.thenReturn(responseEntity);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> However the above code does not work, it shows that responseEntitty is
> null. How can I correct my test to properly mock
> restTemplate.exchange?

It returns null because using:

```
@Mock
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

If the goal is to mock with `MockRestServiceServer` instead of `Mockito`, it should be:

```
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

or `RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate()`
when the same instance is provided to `MockRestServiceServer` and `SomeService`.

For example:

```
@Test
public void methodWithPostCallTest() throws URISyntaxException {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    MockRestServiceServer mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
    mockServer.expect(ExpectedCount.once(), 
            requestTo(new URI("post-method-url")))
            .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
            .andRespond(withStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body("response-body")
          );

    YourService yourService = new YourService(restTemplate);
    String response = yourService.methodWhichExecutesPostCall();

    mockServer.verify();
    assertEquals("response-body", response);  
}
```

Using `MockRestServiceServer`, it would return mock response for any [RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) method for a `POST` call - `postForEntity`, `postForObject` or `exchange`.

More details: [Testing Client Applications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-client)

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn’t matter which of the methods you call on RestTemplate, there is a very easy way to mock it.
Just add default Answer to constructor when you create mock of your RestTemplate.
I'll show you how I solved this problem below.

I created 2 auxiliary methods to generate a new test object with mocked RestTemplate with behavior I needed before each test.
Firstly, I created a method that initializes the mocks, taking parameter `org.mockito.stubbing.Answer` as a default RestTemplate mock Answer.

```
private void initMocks(Answer<?> restTemplateAnswer) {
    restTemplate = mock(RestTemplate.class, restTemplateAnswer);
    //... your additional mocks initialization
}
```

Then I added a method that creates my object under test.

```
private void createJobServiceWithMocks(Answer<?> restTemplateAnswer) {
    initMocks(restTemplateAnswer);
    jobService = new JobService(restTemplate);
}
```

Now, before any test, I can construct the object under test with the RestTemplate behavior I need.
I can do it in this way:

```
createJobServiceWithMocks(invocation -> new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED));
```

or so

```
var expectedResponse = new ResponseEntity<>(new JobDetailsResponse(), HttpStatus.CREATED);
createJobServiceWithMocks(invocation -> expectedResponse);
```

or even like that

```
createJobServiceWithMocks(invocation -> {
             throw new RestClientException("some message");
         });
```

Answer (score -1):

If your intention is test the service without care about the rest call, I will suggest to not use any annotation in your unit test to simplify the test.

So, my suggestion is refactor your service to receive the resttemplate using injection constructor. This will facilitate the test. Example:

```
@Service
class SomeService {
    @AutoWired
    SomeService(TestTemplateObjects restTemplateObjects) {
        this.restTemplateObjects = restTemplateObjects;
    }
}
```

The RestTemplate as component, to be injected and mocked after:

```
@Component
public class RestTemplateObjects {

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public RestTemplateObjects () {
        this.restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        // you can add extra setup the restTemplate here, like errorHandler or converters
    }

    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
        return restTemplate;
    }
}
```

And the test:

```
public void test() {

    when(mockedRestTemplateObject.get).thenReturn(mockRestTemplate);

    //mock restTemplate.exchange
    when(mockRestTemplate.exchange(...)).thenReturn(mockedResponseEntity);

    SomeService someService = new SomeService(mockedRestTemplateObject);
    someService.getListofObjectsA();
}
```

In this way, you have direct access to mock the rest template by the SomeService constructor.

Comment: Why the negative vote?