# How to mock restTemplate.Exchange that I have used inside a method using Mockito

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, mockito

I'm trying to mock the  RestTemplate exchange below method but having issue

```
ResponseEntity<List<Stock>> response = restTemplate.exchange(UrlBatch, HttpMethod.POST, buildHttpEntity(reqBody), new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Stock>>() {
                            });
```

I tried the below approach

```
  ResponseEntity<List<Stock>> response=new ResponseEntity<List<Stock>>(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
  Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(
                    ArgumentMatcher.eq("/objects/get-objectA"),
                    ArgumentMatcher.eq(HttpMethod.POST),
                    ArgumentMatcher.<HttpEntity<List<Stop>>>any(),
                    ArgumentMatcher.<ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Stock>>>any())
                ).thenReturn(response);
```

Comment: you are not mocking anything in above code

Comment: How to mock the above code. I mean the response that i will be getting @Deadpool

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I mock a REST template exchange?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486521/how-do-i-mock-a-rest-template-exchange)

Comment: @Deadpool I checked that before posting here but The HTTPStatus.ACCEPTED gives me error

Comment: can you please add more code with error message and also change title appropriately

Comment: @Deadpool I have added more code

Comment: so you getting null? or error?