# Mocking REST API calls with SpringBoot profiles

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, web-applications

I have recently started out with Spring and am unsure about how to approach this issue. I have a Spring boot program which makes calls to remote REST APIs. For example an `AddressService` class with `getAddress(String user)` method, which makes a HTTP call and returns a JSON response. I would like to set up Spring profiles for development purposes `local`, `dev`, `uat`, `prod`.

When the program is running with the `local` profile, I would like to "mock" these external API calls with an expected JSON response, so I can just test logic, but when it is run in any of the other profiles I would like to make the actual calls. How can I go about doing this? From what I read, there's many ways people approach this, using `WireMock`, `RestTemplate`, `Mockito` etc. I'm confused about which is the way to go.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

WireMock,Mockit is for unittest, to mock the real request. Example here:
[How do I mock a REST template exchange?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486521/how-do-i-mock-a-rest-template-exchange)

When you need a running implementation with a mock, i think the easiest way is that you have a interface

```
public interface AdressAdapter {
    public List<Adress> getAddress(String name);
}
```

And two different implementations depending on the profile.

```
@Profile("local")
public class DummyAdress implements AdressAdapter{
    @Override
    public List<Adress> getAddress(String name) {
        //Mock here something
        return null;
    }
}
```

! means NOT locale profile in this case.

```
@Profile("!local")
public class RealAdress implements AdressAdapter{
    @Override
    public List<Adress> getAddress(String name) {
        //Make Restcall
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: but how would you mock a call to a downstream API in your code?  I am not talking about doing it in test, but in the code?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use different `application.properties` files depending on your profile. That way, you just change the url to a mock server for your `local` profile.

So what you have to do is :

1. Create another application.properties in your `resources` folder named : `application-local.properties`.
2. Change the url of the desired service.
3. Start your application with the VM option `-Dspring.profiles.active=local`.

Here is a [link](https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-profile-based-properties-and-yaml-example/) that describe well what you want to achieve.

For your mock server, you could use [Wiremock](http://wiremock.org/docs/configuration/), [Mountebank](http://www.mbtest.org/docs/gettingStarted), [Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/mock-servers/setting-up-mock/),... that can be start separately and mock specific endpoints to return what you want.