# Mockito: Verify if restTemplate.exchange() is called

Tags: java, testing, mockito, spring-resttemplate

i try to test my SpringBoot application with Mockito.
Is it possible to check if a restTemplate.exchange() method is called n times?

For example:

```
verify(restTemplate, times(1))
    .exchange(myURL, method, requestEntity, responseType)
```

Comment: i would bet on it (it is possible)! what is the problem? (overload (+var args) methods  (as `exchange` is)  are little/more tricky to match/verify)

Comment: what causes you think that it cannot when compared to other class ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
verify(restTemplate, times(1))
    .exchange(
        ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),
        ArgumentMatchers.any(HttpMethod.class),
        ArgumentMatchers.any(HttpEntity.class),
        ArgumentMatchers.<Class<Object>>any()
    );
```

More on this topic: [How do I mock a REST template exchange?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486521/how-do-i-mock-a-rest-template-exchange)